# parsing expression in geom_text: character, number and special characters

Tags: r, ggplot2

**My Problem**

I'd like to annotate each facet of a `ggplot()` with a expression that is combinination of values resulting from a statistical test.
I'm not being able to get the string parsed within a `geom_text()`.

A similar problem was partially covered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4408414/cannot-concatenate-more-than-3-elements-in-an-expression-for-ggplot2s-geom-text). Unfortunately I'm not being able to apply that specific example.

**My Objective**

parsing a expression combine numbers, characters and special characters. in this case, lab2 of example below.

**Example**

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) + geom_point()

custom_label <- data.frame(cyl = c(4,6,8),
                           wt = c(5,5,5),
                           lab = c('X^2','X^2','X^2'),
                           lab2 = c('X^2: 18.5342, p =3e-04',
                                   'X^2: 4.7512, p =0.1909',
                                   'X^2: 15.3266, p =0.0016'))
p + facet_grid(. ~ cyl) +
  geom_text(data = custom_label, aes(x=30, y=wt, label = lab2), size = 3, parse = T)
```

This works fine with using custom_label$lab but fails with lab2.

I'd appreciate any help with this. Please let me know if I'm being clear in presenting my problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Actually I would argue that you did not get a real `chi-squared`, but instead got an `X^2`. That might be OK since the sample estimate of a chi-squared variate is often labeled as X^2, but if you want `chi` you need to use `chi`  (or `Chi` for capital-Greek-chi that admittedly looks a lot like an "X"). You need to use double quotes and construct as a `plotmath` expression with proper `~` and `*` separators:

```
                      lab2 = c("chi^2*':'~18.5*', p =3e-04'",
                               "chi^2*':'~4.7*', p =0.1909'",
                               "chi^2*':'~15.3*', p =0.0016'")
```

Run the examples and demos for plotmath:

```
?plotmath
demo(plotmath)
```

Comment: I believe those should be == instead of =, big guy :)

Comment: If I were going the whole-hog plotmath route, I would need them but those were enclosed in quotes (to retain the commas) so they did not. (I did test and figured the positioning was something the OP was not asking about so did not fix that problem..)

Comment: If you wanted it to be pure plotmath, but retain the commas, then you might put it in as: `"list(chi^2*':'~18.5*phantom(), p == 3e-04)"`. Or just: `"list(chi^2*':'~18.5, p == 3e-04)"`.  There is a slight difference in the text "=" and what you get with plotmath `==`.